# How to make vanilla Bootstrap work with React on Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I don't want to use the `react-bootstrap` components,

I simply want to use Bootstrap on a React site.

I installed Bootstrap with npm : `npm install bootstrap`

and added it in my package.json dependencies :

```
"dependencies": {
    [...],
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.5"
}
```

and added it to my App.js file : `import bootstrap from 'bootstrap';`

However, the style is not applied and it looks like a website from 1995.

I also tried to add `import bootstrap from 'bootstrap';` to my index.js without success.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to add the CSS to your page. You can either:

- copy bootstrap.css from `node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/`, put it in a public folder, and add it to your page normally (which isn't ideal if you ever plan to upgrade bootstrap)

or

- if you're using something like webpack or gulp, you can just add bootstrap.css to your CSS bundle